# Access column returned by psql from bash

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to use value returned by psql in bash. This is the script:

```sh
psql "connection parameters" -c "SELECT pg_database_size('dbname');"
```

The output is like this:

```
 pg_database_size 
------------------
          5773072
(1 row)
```

But I only want the `5773072` so I can use it in logging. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`-t` (`--tuples-only`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) option might be used also:

```
psql "connection parameters" -t -c "SELECT pg_database_size('dbname');"
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @Milen already provided, you may want `-A` (`--no-align`) to remove leading white space:

```sh
psql "con params" -tAc "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('mydb'))"
```

As an aside: [`pg_size_pretty()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) may or may not be of interest.

Comment: I think this is better than the confirmed answer

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
psql "connection parameters" -c "SELECT pg_database_size('dbname');" | tail -3 | head -1 | tr -d ' '
```